# Nodejs/Express Ajax call to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I am looking for a sample and how to make ajax call to get data from MySQL for Nodejs/Express projects.
 I have database connection established in app.js file. That's starts when node is running. This is db.js file.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
let db_connected =false;
const ut_mysql_con = mysql.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'root',
     password: 'pass',
     database: "db"

 });

 mysql_con.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   else {
    console.log("Connected!");
    db_connected = true;
 }
});
module.exports = mysql_con;
module.exports.db_connected = db_connected;
```

I also have an ejs file for front end from which ajax call is made.

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(()=>{
     //this where actual call would go if i knew how to do it.
  });
 </script>
```

I am comfortable with writing actually queries, but can't find a way of properly using ajax.
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Can you share any code you have started?

Comment: Added to original post. Thanks

Comment: Right now, you're not exposing any sort of endpoint to fetch the results from. Take a look at creating an API with Express (or similar framework) that allows you to create a router with endpoints you can fetch data from.